# Calculated Column to assign numeric value to written month

Tags: calculated-column, sharepoint-list

My list has a field for report month. The month is selected from a list and is displayed in text format (Jan, Feb, etc.) For sorting puposes, I want to add a calculated column that will assign the month's numeric value (01, 02, etc.). Any help writing the formula would be extremely, greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to convert the `Text date` into `Date` and then extract the `month`.

Try this:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE("1-",MonthColumnName)))
```

1 being the first day of the month (and a dash) is added to convert text into date

[image]

More details on  DateValue [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) and Month [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MONTH-function-579a2881-199b-48b2-ab90-ddba0eba86e8)

Comment: Although my own situation uses fully spelled-out month names, and thus requires a different syntax within the DATEVALUE function, this answer still gave me enough to figure out what I needed.